# Package not found - Problems with a project in Vue3

Tags: vuejs3, npm-scripts, npm-run

I'm learning Vue3, but I'm with some problems when I try to create the project.
I'm using Windows 10 and the more update versions of node and vue.
This is my steps.

[Initial configs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7PU1.jpg)

[Create app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAXJW.jpg)

[Starting server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMrXj.jpg)

[The error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFtOR.jpg)

I'm try update node and vue, clear the cash files, restart pc and server.

Comment: Please post code as code, not images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating Vue project with webpack is a bit out of date as per now. It mostly come with `vite` now which gives more faster developing experience.

```
npm init vue@latest
```

This is an interactive command to create a new project with vuejs with the latest features.

Comment: I find the problem. When I create the project, in configs I don't put the ESLint and Prettier.

Comment: I solve the other problem.
DON'T USE ESPECIAL CARACTERS (#$%, etc) to name files and dir.

Comment: Special chars. in file|folder names are always discouraged. Cheers! :)